# How to include servlet in JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jsf-2

How can I include a servlet page , in a JSF page. Is there a way to do that?

Thank!

Comment: Check [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/213079/JSF/java/call-servlet-JSF-without-dispatch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's possible with a custom `UIComponent`. My colleague Arjan Tijms has written a blog article about this 2 years ago: [Facelets and legacy JSP](http://jdevelopment.nl/facelets-legacy-jsp/).

It's some code, but the principle is easy, the component does a [`RequestDispatcher#include()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) with a custom [`HttpServletResponseWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) which captures the written output and then writes it to the body of the JSF component.

Since recently, this component is also available as `<o:resourceInclude>` of the [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) library, maintained by Arjan and me.

Last but not least, I'd like to repeat his last words.

> *I wouldn’t recommend using this as a lasting solution, but it might ease a migration from legacy JSP with smelly scriptlets and all on them to a more sane and modern Facelets application.*